# How can I export an Illustrator JPEG - PNG while keeping the whitespace?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, jpg, white-space

I  created a logo in illustrator for a client. When I export it and save it as a JPEG the image is clear but the artboard gets cut of. It only saves the logo itself, there is no white space. How can I export it with the white space?

My client wants to use the logo for his screen background. So I need a very crisp image that's nicely centered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If **Exporting**, tick the **Use Artboards** box in the Export dialog window and select the artboard number you want to export (or all).

[image]

If using **Save For Web**, tick **Clip to Artboard** in the **Save for Web** dialog window if you wish Save for Web to use the artboard as the final size of the image.

[image]

I realize the term "clip" may be counter intuitive. But with it UNticked, AI uses the artwork bounds as the image size. *With* it ticked, AI uses the artboard size.

Comment: ▲ **This** is the way to do it. Funny story, back when I started using Illustrator I didn't know how to do it. I used to just make a box (filling the artboard) and set stroke/fill to none and put in in a locked layer.

Comment: @Scott thanks, it works just fine. ;) When I try to do this with a PNG and use it as a screen background it comes out blurry. Any idea why? Or how to fix it?

Comment: @Bianca I would use Save for Web and also choose optimized. Make sure you are saving it to the correct size as well.

Comment: I don't want to send my client more than one logo file. If I have to save it to the correct size, then I have to send him one for the screen background, one for his email signature, one for his profile picture, and anything else he comes up with. Is it professional to send so many files? Consider I already sent him one png and one jpeg with white background.

Comment: @Bianca, I would say yes, just label all the filenames clearly like `LogoSignature.png` and `LogoBackground.png` and `LogoProfile.jpg`.

Comment: @Bianca for client approval, I'd *really* suggest a PDF and not a raster format. And you can have multiple pages in a PDF if necessary.

Comment: Yes, but you can't use a pdf as a background, or as profile picture, or as an email signature?!?

Comment: Oh.. good point :)

Comment: Of course, when it was still a work in progress I worked with pdf files. But now that he's aprroved the logo he needs jpeg's and png's.